# File upload using Razor without MVC

Tags: javascript, razor, razor-pages

I'm brand new in my position and fresh out of college. The team I'm developing on refuses to use MVC (not really sure why) and all of the pages are cshtml razor pages. I've been tasked with creating a file upload for the site, is there a way to do this only using Razor and javascript?

Comment: Any reason why you have to use javascript and can't use the input "file" control and post the file?

Comment: @WooHoo no reason. This is my first time really diving in deep to ASP. I know how to create the form element and what not. I really am just stumped on how to pass the file to my server/database.

Comment: @AllenMiller If you can't post the form then you will need to use ajax - javascript has a built in api for getting your file data. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've taken most of this from the url below.

https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/forms/file-upload

Create the upload page, this will allow the user to select a file, when the user clicks on the submit input it will post the file back to the server.

```
@page
@model UploadFileModel
@{
}
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" asp-for="Upload" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

You can handle the post request using the following code, which will save the file to an uploads folder.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace RazorPagesForms.Pages
{
    public class UploadFileModel : PageModel
    {
        private IHostingEnvironment _environment;
        public UploadFileModel(IHostingEnvironment environment)
        {
            _environment = environment;
        }
        [BindProperty]
        public IFormFile Upload { get; set; }
        public async Task OnPostAsync()
        {
            var file = Path.Combine(_environment.ContentRootPath, "uploads", Upload.FileName);
            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Create))
            {
                await Upload.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
            }
        }
    }
}
```